# Use CUDA in order to compute efficiently the positions of a sorted array where an element changes

Tags: c++, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

Let's say we have this sorted array

```
     0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 10 10 10
```

I would like to find efficiently the positions where an element changes. For example in our array the positions are the following:

```
    0 1 5 10 11
```

I know there are a few libraries(Thrust) that can achieve this, however I would like to create my own efficient implementation for educational purposes.

You can find the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/Wu34F4M2

It includes validation as well.

The kernel is the following function:

```
__global__ void findPositions(int *device_data, 
         int totalAmountOfValuesPerThread, int* pos_ptr, int N){

   int res1 = 9999999;
   int res2 = 9999999;
   int index = totalAmountOfValuesPerThread*(threadIdx.x + 
                  blockIdx.x*blockDim.x);
   int start = index; //from this index each thread will begin searching
   if(start < N){ //if the index is out of bounds do nothing
      if(start!=0){ //if start is not in the beginning, check the previous value
        if(device_data[start-1] != device_data[start]){
        res1 = start;
        }
      }
      else res1 = start; //since it's the 
          //beginning we update the first output buffer for the thread
      pos_ptr[index] = res1;

      start++; //move to the next place and see if the 
      //second output buffer needs updating or not

      if(start < N && device_data[start] != device_data[start-1]){
         res2 = start;
      }

      if((index+1) < N)
        pos_ptr[index+ 1] = res2;
      }
}
```

I create so many threads so that each thread has to work with two values of the array.

1. `device_data` has all the numbers stored in the array
2. `totalAmountOfValuesPerThread` in this case is the total amount of values that each thread will have to work with
3. `pos_ptr` has the same length as `device_data`, each thread writes the results of the buffers to this `device_vector`
4. `N` is the total amount of numbers in the `device_data` array

In the output buffers called `res1` and `res2` each thread either saves a position that has not been found before, or it leaves it as it is.

Example:

```
  0   <---- thread 1
  1
  1   <---- thread 2
  1
  2   <---- thread 3
  2
  3   <---- thread 4
```

The output buffers of each thread, assuming that the big number 9999999 is `inf` would be:

```
  thread1 => {res1=0, res2=1}
  thread2 => {res1=inf, res2=inf}
  thread3 => {res1=4, res2=inf}
  thread4 => {res1=6, res2=inf}
```

Each thread will update the `pos_ptr` `device_vector` so this vector will have as a result the following:

```
  pos_ptr =>{0, 1, inf, inf, 4, inf, 6, inf}
```

After finishing the kernel, I sort the vector by using the library `Thrust` and save the results inside a host vector called `host_pos`. So the `host_pos` vector will have the following:

```
  host_pos => {0, 1, 4, 6, inf, inf, inf, inf}
```

This implementation is horrible because

1. A lot of branches inside the kernel are created, so inefficient wrap handling will occur
2. I assume that each thread works with 2 values only, which is very inefficient because too many threads are created
3. I create and transfer a `device_vector` which is as big as the input and also resides in the global memory. Each thread accesses this vector in order to write the results, this is very inefficient.

Here is test case for input of size `1 000 000` when having `512` threads in each block.

```
     CPU time: 0.000875688 seconds
     GPU time: 1.35816 seconds
```

Another testcase for input of size `10 000 000`

```
     CPU time: 0.0979209
     GPU time: 1.41298 seconds
```

Notice that the CPU version became almost 100 times slower while the GPU gave almost the same times.

Unfortunately my GPU hasn't got enough memory, so let's try for `50 000 000`

```
     CPU time: 0.459832 seconds
     GPU time: 1.59248 seconds
```

As I understand, for huge inputs my GPU implementation might become faster, however I believe a much more efficient approach might make the implementation a lot faster even for smaller inputs.

What design would you suggest in order to make my algorithm run faster? Unfortunately I can't think of anything better.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should put the compilation command you use. Thus it's easier for other people to help you and everyone can have the same nvcc options (e.g. architecture used).

Comment: Also, note that you are timing the memory allocations and transfers for the GPU implementation. Keep in mind that these can be particularly slow operations, you can have a better idea of this by running `nvvp`.

Comment: A quick look at the timeline for 10000000 elements shows that only 3~4% of the computation time is spent in your kernel, the rest is spent in Thrust's scans and reductions (tested with a GeForce GT 650M).

Comment: Hello sorry I did not see the message earlier(I went to sleep), the compilation command is simply

`nvcc test.cu -O3`

would it be more efficient if I did not use sorting at all? I would still have to write the results of each buffer in order to be able to have them later on. Having a vector unfortunately is not a good option because if I'm correct, it's not supported. I can't think of a way that could avoid using so much shared output memory among the threads...I guess avoiding the branching factor is not possible because each thread has to know whether it's reading in bound values or not.

Comment: just for reference, would you please share the thrust function to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really understanding any of the reasons why you think this is horrible.  Too many threads?  What is the definition of too many threads?  One thread per input element is a *very common* thread strategy in CUDA programs.

Since you seem to be willing to consider using thrust for much of the work (e.g. you're willing to call thrust::sort after you're done marking the data) and taking into account BenC's observation (that you are spending a lot of time trying to optimize 3% of your total run time) maybe you can have a much bigger impact by just making better use of thrust.

Suggestions:

1. Make your kernel as simple as possible.  Just have each thread look
   at one element, and decide to make a marker based on comparing with
   the previous element.  I'm not sure any significant gains are made
   by having each thread handle 2 elements.  Alternatively, have a kernel that creates a *much* smaller number of blocks, but have them loop through your overall `device_data` array, marking the boundaries as they go.  This might make a noticeable improvement in your kernel.  But again, optimizing 3% is not necessarily where you want to spend a lot of effort.
2. Your kernel is going to be memory bandwidth bound.  Therefore rather than worry about things like branching, I would focus on efficient use of memory, i.e. minimizing reads and writes to global memory, and look for opportunities to make sure your reads and writes are coalesced.  Test your kernel independently of the rest of the program, and use the visual profiler to tell you if you've done a good job on memory operations.
3. Consider using shared memory.  By having every thread load it's respective element into shared memory, you can easily coalesce all the global reads (and make sure you only read every global element once, or almost every element once) and then operate out of shared memory, i.e. have each thread compare it's element to the previous one in shared memory.
4. Once you've created your `pos_ptr` array, let's note that apart from
   the `inf` values *it is already sorted*.  So maybe there's a smarter
   option than "thrust::sort" followed by trimming the array, to
   produce the result.  Take a look at thrust functions like
   `remove_if` and `copy_if`.  I haven't benchmarked it, but my guess
   is they will be signficantly less expensive than sort, followed by
   trimming the array (removing the inf values).

Comment: thank you very much, I would say that my implementation is bad due to the memory consumption, for example I pass to the kernel an array with the data and another array of the same size that will save the results. However the final results will probably be much less than the actual amount of output memory that I have allocated, which is why I guess a lot of time is spent on allocating memory that I will probably never need in the end. On the other hand I'm not sure how I could avoid the "inf" values but at the same time have the threads being totally independent from each other.

Comment: I would not agree that this is a good criticism either, because in the worst case you could have a new element at every position.  Then you need that much memory.  So what is the point of trying to make the algorithm use less?  The most valid criticism I see is that it runs slower than the CPU version, and for that you should not focus on the 3% but on the overall algorithm, as BenC pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, you are right, hopefully after your suggestions and the changes I will make, the gpu implementation will become faster!

Comment: I made an implementation and it's faster! I used one thread instead of two and the kernel code became much more simpler. For some reason the program run very slow the first time I executed it however the second time it run faster. I then realized that I had to include `-arch=sm_21`. Right now for 50 000 000 values the `CPU` time is `0.526013` seconds while the `GPU` time is `0.0955` seconds. Wow that's a nice difference for me because I won't be running the operation just once, if I decide to run it 10 times the part of my program that uses this operation will most likely run 5 times faster!